# Каким образом стоит спроектировать БД phpmysql

Tags: sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

как спроектировать БД так, чтобы при внесение для определенного названия можно было ввести для каждого архива свои  ббк удк и инвентарные номера. Т.е. есть название - оно хранится в нескольких архивах , в каждом определенный ббк удк и инвентарные номера.
Мои мысли таковы - сделать таблицы еще archive(id,name),infprintedit_archives(id,infprintedit_id,archive_id,bbk,udk,inventnumber). archive - для информации о названиях архивов, infprintedit_archives - для связи таблиц.
Подскажите пожалуйста , как лучше сделать.

```
CREATE TABLE infprintedit (
  id int NOT NULL,
  file text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  title text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  publicationtype text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  author text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  place text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  year text,
  publisher text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  compedit text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  countpages text,
  archive text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  BBK text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  UDK text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  inventnumber text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  numbinstances text,
  user_id int DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE users (
  id int NOT NULL,
  familiya text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  imya text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  otchestvo text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  login text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  pass text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  role text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

ALTER TABLE infprintedit
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
  ADD KEY FK_user_id (user_id);

ALTER TABLE users
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE infprintedit
  MODIFY id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=41;

ALTER TABLE users
  MODIFY id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=82;

ALTER TABLE infprintedit
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id);
COMMIT;
```

ну и  мой вариант выглядит так

```
CREATE TABLE infprintedit (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  file text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  title text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  publicationtype text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  author text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  place text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  year text,
  publisher text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  compedit text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  countpages text,
  user_id int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE archives (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE infprintedit_archives (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  infprintedit_id int,
  archive_id int,
  BBK text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  UDK text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  inventnumber text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (infprintedit_id) REFERENCES infprintedit (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (archive_id) REFERENCES archives (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: кроме `TEXT` там еще `varchar` есть, начните с изучения типов данных лучше, а кодировки и т.п. на уровне БД выставите а не тут.

Comment: @teran я отправил код с дампа. Я попросил подсказку, как лучше будет поступить.

Comment: *Я попросил подсказку, как лучше будет поступить* - и Вам правильно подсказали: "начните с изучения типов данных". Впрочем, не только их. Вообще неплохо бы изучить теорию анализа предметной области и построения ER-диаграмм.